# How to use Linq to sort an array by Length and then value

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

Given the following values in order :

> 011124
>   01112
>   011123
>   1905

How could I use Linq to sort this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() { "011124", "01112", "011123", "1905" };
```

.. so it is effectively this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() { "011124", "011123", "01112", "1905" };
```

(updated: added '1905' as the previous demo would have sorted easily with an int sort -- sorry for the confusion)

Comment: So you want to store the numbers in descending order by the arthimatic value of the strings? What happens when you have a value of "0000001"?

Comment: If you're trying to use the strings to store integers and compare them in an integer fashion, is there any reason you're using strings at all? Life tends to be get a lot easier when you keep data in its "natural" format.

Comment: Yes, using strings, as some of the numbers require the 0 at the front.  Storing as int, removes this.  Updating example to add another value into the mix.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers.  I wish I could pick everyone for 'correct' solution however since this isn't possible, I have to go with the example that uses `Convert.ToInt32()` as this returns a 0 on non-convertible numbers where `int.Parse()` would throw an exception. Both are good, and truly do appreciate everyones input.  I have voted everyone up as well :)

Comment: @SanuelJackson That's not entirely correct. [`Convert.ToInt32` will internally call `int.Parse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,fc990bd1275d43d6), which will throw an exception if it is a non-convertible string. Only if the `string` is null, then it will return 0.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - correct.  What I meant is the trapping is automatic in Convert.ToInt32  :) ...  you understood what I meant though  ^^ .  All are good examples, and under conditions where I need more control over invalid values, .Parse() is better.  :)  .   Appreciate all of the insight into this though, and the very fast and accurate feedback.  Just wish all my questions were this 'easy' to solve lol.  For me, this was boggling as I am not that good with Linq yet -- sort of toes in the water atm.

Comment: @SanuelJackson If you really want to be safe, you can always go with `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - also correct :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
var sortedValues = values
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
    .ThenByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

If you really need use it as a List, then add `ToList()` at the end.

Comment: Looks good.  could you code format the post again pls.  Going to try this.

Comment: I am curious about the `Convert.ToInt32(x)`. Is that actually going to be the resulting value (eg :  011123 would end up as 11123)  ?  I need to keep the 0 in front.

Comment: @SanuelJackson It doesn't matter, it's only for the sake of ordering. It will still yield a `IOrderedEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: perfect :).  times like this I really wish StackOverflow would let me choose more than one answer as correct.  I posted a comment on original thread explaining why I chose yours.

Comment: @SanuelJackson See my remarks in the question comments.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume you actually care about the *value* of each integer. If so:

```
var sortedValues = values.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
                         .ThenByDescending(x => int.Parse(x));
```

This will yield a deferred `IOrderedEnumerable<string>`. The `int.Parse` is only for the purpose of secondary ordering. If you need to materialize it, `ToArray` or `ToList` will need to be called.

Comment: Needs to be string value comparison. The 0 in front matters.

Comment: thank you.  voted up.  see comments in original post for 'answer' selection.  really wish I could choose everyone :S .

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers here are written using Lambda Syntax, if you want query syntax try this. Result should be the same.

```
var sortedValues = from x in values
                   orderby x.Length descending, x descending
                   select x;
```

Comment: orderby x.Length descending, x

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon what about it?

Comment: Correction. You referring to query vs method syntax. Both are using LINQ.

Comment: thank you. voted up. see comments in original post for 'answer' selection. really wish I could choose everyone :S .

I do like the variation in syntax.  Still kind of new(ish) to Linq coding, so nice to see another example how to use it's query syntax.  :)

Comment: @FahadJameel first by length, then by content of x (as per OPs question)

Answer (score 2):

```
values.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ThenByDescending(x => int.Parse(x));
```

Comment: thank you. voted up. see comments in original post for 'answer' selection. really wish I could choose everyone :S .